# Am I normalizing correctly?

Tags: sql, normalization, database-normalization

I just wanted to see if Im normalizing my table correctly based on the  following FD

[image]

Here are the tables I came up with after 2NF and 3NF.

```
Table 1 - (__Client ID__,CLient Name, VetID)
Table 2 - (__Client ID__,__Pet ID__, Pet Name, Pet wt)
Table 3 - (__Vet ID__, Vet Name)
```

The correct structure would be appreciated with an explanation if mine is wrong. Thanks!

Followup: Can normalization result in different table structures?(Depending on how you do it)

EDIT: I should have tagged homework(not being able to). Basically I trying to figure out why my solution is different from the one posted in class here http://tinypic.com/r/2nqtv7b/5

Comment: Seems ok. Normalization of the 2NF and 3NF cannot go in different directions - normalized tables should look the same. The only difference would occur (expect the obvious name and order of the columns) if other normalization process would be incomplete.

Comment: A pet can change owner. If you are logging pet specific information, the relation should be many to many. If you’re only interested in the pet as a property of an owner, your current design is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that in the Client's relation (Table 1) that the VetID belongs to this table. This is because, VetID does not depend on ClientID - I am not sure why you say that there is partial dependency?

In Table2 (Pet Table), you have 2 choices for the PK, either PetID or PetID+ClientID. We don't have information on PetID and how it is generated, so it is (safer) to assume the combined key. However, combined keys are not your first choice in real applications.

What seems to be missing here is the purpose of the schema. I would imagine that this may be a schema for a vet's clinic. I expect that you want to record every visit of a client and his/her pet. In which case, you need to have a Visit relations (Table 4).

Comment: If your case is such that each client has specific vet that deals with, then it is correct to include vetid in table 1.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

> Only Client Details
>  
>   Table 1 - (**Client ID**,CLient Name, Other Client Columns)
>
> Only Pet Details
>  Table 2 - (**Pet ID**, Pet Name_ Othe Pet Columns)
>
> Only Vet Details
>  Table 3 - (**Vet ID**, Vet Name, Other Vet Columns)
>
> Which clients has which Pets and What Vets they go to
>  Table 4 - (**ID**,Vet
>   ID,Client ID,Pet ID)